# Is it correct to use で in this sentence if I want to convey "and"?

Tags: grammar, nuances, syntax

My penpal and I were talking about a particular video game and I wanted to tell him: *"The PC version (of the game) has its release date someday next month and I just can't wait any longer!"*

> **PC**版の発売日はいつか来月なの**で**もうこれ以上待てませんよ！

The above sentence was my attempt, but now that I wrote it I'm not really sure if I used 「で」 correctly here. Is there a better/more natural way of saying it, not just the "and" part but maybe the whole sentence in general?

I would appreciate any type of feedback/corrections as I'm still a novice.

Comment: Think of this as なので not just で

Comment: You'll want to say 「来月のいつか」or sometime next month. The way you have it now, it makes it seem like it may happen sometime in the future but that it is uncertain.

Comment: @virmaior That's why I'm unsure. To me なので is like "because of" and I want to say "and", not "because".

Comment: Your use of 「なので」 is natural.  We do use it that way in informal speech.  Whether it makes sense or seems correct when translated to English is of no relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation of "and" is not wrong, but your grammatical interpretation may be wrong.

> AはBなので

is

> AはB + 連体形 of 助動詞 "だ" + 接続助詞 "ので".

However, "ので" means "because", and it may not fit your example.
Ending the first clause with 連用形 (in this case "で" from "だ") or 接続助詞 "が" (in this case "だが") looks better.

Apart from "and", "いつか来月" does not make sense and should be "来月のいつか".

My translation would be:

> PC版は来月発売ですが、待ち切れません。
>   I'm very looking forward to playing the PC version, which will be released next month.

or

> PC版が来月発売で、待ち切れません。
>   As PC version is released soon, I'm always thinking about it.

Comment: You're sure ですが is better? Sounds to me like you're changing the meaning to like 'even though it's still a month away I can't wait', but I feel like the OP's intent is more of 'it's only a month away now and I can't wait' (in which case just で might be best - 発売日は来月で待ちきれない).

Comment: @Sjiveru "が" does not necessarily mean "although" and it is often used to introduce a topic. OP's intent について **ですが,** I had thought of two possibilities: "the release has been postponed several times" and "the first sentence is just an introduction". However, now I feel that another interpretation based on your comment is correct: "the speaker is always thinking about the game, because it will be released soon".

Comment: @kmk I've only ever heard that usage with ですが as in something like 'yeah, about that', but that may be due to my limited experience ^_^